# Why does the c++ variable not get detleted immediately?

Tags: c++, pointers, garbage

I'd like to know why is it that the data that is pointed to when you return from a function, is not deleted immediately. In the snippet of code below,I expect that when I return the address of x to the pointer to initialise it when returning from function, the data stored in the address of x should be deleted immediately. However I am still able to get the correct value in main and then only after one more line of code does it suddenly turn into garbage? Why does this not happen immediately

```
int* function(int x)
{
    cout << x << endl; // This outputs 5 as expected
    return &x;
}

int main()
{
    int* a = function(5);


    cout << *a; // This still outputs 5. Why?
    cout << endl;

    cout << *a; // It is garbage here as expected
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Variables are not deleted. Their values might become deleted.

Comment: @Niall Even if it did: it wouldn't apply to local variables (at least in C++), and of course, garbage collection won't recycle the memory until it's needed.

Comment: As soon as x goes out of scope, accessing its contents is undefined as the location that stores them may be re-used. That doesn't mean they _are_ reused immediately -it can  happen immediately, after a while or never

Comment: My [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26705204/509868) to another similar question may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning the address of a local variable invokes undefined behavior. So, you're just lucky.

The local variable (allocated on the stack) gets deleted when it leaves it's scope, which in your case is when `function()` ends. However, after the variable leaves the scope, the memory it occupies is not rewritten immediately and unless that memory is reused the value of `x` will stay there.

Since it invokes UB, your attempt to read the contents of that memory can result in reading the right value, reading garbage, your programm crashing, or anything else.

Comment: Or unlucky, as the case may be :)

Comment: That's not  an answer to the question, which is about the timing of garbage collection.

Comment: @Paul, well, because there is no garbage collection at all?

Comment: There is. There's no automatic garbage collection, but there's recycling of storage. Maybe I should have used a different term

Comment: @Paul: The question doesn't mention garbage collection. It asks why the dead variable doesn't immediately have a garbage value. The answer is UB (although a better answer would also explain that the apparent value is unlikely to change until the storage is reused).

Comment: OK, wrong term. I was trying to make the point that he question is about storage recycling, not about whether the behaviour is defined

Answer (score 1):

Returning address of local variable is undefined. Undefined means you can't predict whether it would output correct OR incorrect result. It's unfortunate that you got correct result.

Answer (score 0):

As you should not be accessing such "garbage" (a technical term), the system is free to deal with it as it sees fit.  For example, there may have been other tasks whose completion *would* have affected correctly-written programs.

Answer (score 0):

When you return the address of a local variable, the resulting
pointer "dangles"; accessing through a dangling pointer, or even
just reading it, is undefined behavior.  Which means that in
theory, anything can happen.  In practice, the compiled code
won't return the memory of the local variables in the function
to the OS; in most OS's, it couldn't even if it wanted to.  So
the memory just sits there, until someone else uses it.  In the
case of memory in a function, it will be reused when you call
another function; until then, you will probably be able to
access it and find the old values.  Debugging builds might
intentionally scribble over the memory on leaving the function,
but the mainstream compilers don't do this.  And of course,
programs like valgrind *might* check that the pointer is valid,
and log an error (but I don't know if valgrind actually catches
this).